# ¿Como puedo quitar el caracter especial [@] al terminar de recorrer mi array en bash?

Tags: array, bash

Ando recorriendo un array pero al momento de imprimir todos los valores que se encuentra dentro de el precisamente en el ultimo me aneza un caracter especial [@]
A continuacion muestro mi codigo

```
for i in $array[@]
do
  echo $i
done
```

y cuando hace la ultima impresion sale algo asi como:

```
ejemplo[@]
```

Comment: Raro, a mi no me sale la @ https://onlinegdb.com/lNji9B3Y_T

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

El problema ahí es el uso de los caracteres [@].

Utiliza lo siguiente:

```
for i in ${array[@]}
do
  echo $i
done
```

Es decir, tan sólo añade los braces "{}"

### Explicacion

El problema aquí es que para recorrer un array necesitas de un mecanismo llamado "parameter expansion", que te proporciona el uso de los corchetes "{}".

De esta manera, lo que esté dentro de los corchetes puede ser tratado como un array (al usar los parentesis cuadrados) o aplicarle mas funciones.